# Google Play Payment Library updated to latest, but still getting error regarding library upgradation

Tags: google-play, android-app-bundle, google-play-billing

I'm trying to upload my app in playstore for internal testing, when I upload the file I'm getting a error that says:

**"We've detected that one or more of the app bundles included in this release are using the following Play Billing Library versions
"AIDL"
These are unsupported versions of Google Play Billing. Upgrade to a supported version to publish this app."**

Here is the screenshot of the exact error
[image: Image Link]
I have no idea why I'm still getting this error, because I'm already using the latest library version which is 6.0.1.
("com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.1")
I tried uploading the file using 4.0.0 & 5.0.0 library versions too, but still got the same error. I've have invalidated & restarted my android studio, cleaned & rebuilt the project, but the error is still there. I'm totally clueless what I'm doing wrong. Can some please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible you are using a 3rd party library for your billing? like 'lib/com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.jar' or something like this?  then you have to upgrade it too

Comment: No I'm not using any third party library for this, I'm using the official SDK from google.